# It this a good implementation of Mediator Design Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I have to explain the mediator design pattern but I am not sure whether I have used it in a right context so I would like to ask you for your opinions. [image]

I have four objects that each of them need to interact with others. So to make the code easier to maintain and reuse  **I add the mediator pattern  so the point is to centralize comples communications and control between related objects.**

[image]

So my questions is: Do you think it **is a good example of Mediator Patterns.** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example I guess...

Mediator are objects which centralise communications to avoid dependencies between every objects which communicate together.

With your sample, I would just add, for instance, a new `WeatherStation` class whose role would be to alert drones and rovers to make them go back home, and explain that thanks to the mediator pattern, there is only `WeatherStation <-> Mediator` interface to implement.

Instead of :

```
WeatherStation<->Scientists
WeatherStation<->Jedays
...
```